# Email screenshot without saving to camera roll

Tags: ios, swift, email

I have the following code which allows a UIButton to capture a partial screenshot and save it to the camera roll - Thanks Lou Franco :)

```
    // Declare the snapshot boundaries
    let top: CGFloat = 100
    let bottom: CGFloat = 60

    // The size of the cropped image
    let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height - top - bottom)

    // Start the context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    // we are going to use context in a couple of places
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // Transform the context so that anything drawn into it is displaced "top" pixels up
    // Something drawn at coordinate (0, 0) will now be drawn at (0, -top)
    // This will result in the "top" pixels being cut off
    // The bottom pixels are cut off because the size of the of the context
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -top)

    // Draw the view into the context (this is the snapshot)
    view.layer.renderInContext(context)
    let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // End the context (this is required to not leak resources)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // Save to photos
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapshot, nil, nil, nil)
```

How would I amend the above code so that:

1. Another UIButton could capture the same partial screenshot and EMAIL it as an attachment?; and
2. Another UIButton could capture the same partial screenshot and SMS it as an attachment?

I realise that my questions may make me look lazy, not so, I'm just very green at the moment :)

I've tried scouring the Web and modifying various snippets of code, but I really am stumped!

Many thanks in advance. Your time and effort is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will set you up for emailing the image.

```
let composer = MFMailComposeViewController()
composer.setToRecipients(["someemail@email.com"])
composer.setMessageBody("Body", isHTML: false)
composer.setSubject("Subject")

let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(snapshot)
composer.addAttachmentData(imageData, mimeType: "image/png", fileName:"myImage")

presentViewController(composer, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To send it as an SMS it's pretty much the exact same process, except this time you use `MFMessageComposeViewController` rather than `MFMailComposeViewController`

Comment: So, I added my code (above) within the @IBAction function for emailing my screenshot, deleted `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapshot, nil, nil, nil)` and added your code. However, I get two errors. For `let image = UIImage("image")` I get a "missing argument label" error. And for `let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage)` I get a "use of unresolved identifier 'my image' " error. I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: You're fine, I wrote most of that code from memory, likely syntax errors. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @PaulSatem Should be okay now. Let me know how you go. You may also want to remove the `UIImage(named: "image")` and just use your snapshot directly.

Comment: Made changes as per your advice as follows : `let image = snapshot
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        composer.addAttachmentData(imageData!, mimeType: "image/png", fileName:"myImage") `. It builds perfectly when I execute the iOS simulator, but I can't test it as I don't seem to have an email function set up on the simulator yet. Superb assistance though - TYVM!

Comment: One more thing, I added `import MessageUI` and also added `class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` . Should I import any more frameworks?

Comment: If your code runs fine without them, then you should be fine. Glad I could help.

Comment: This may be a redundant question, but should my code now at least produce a draft email window in the iOS simulator when I run the app? I realise I cannot send mail via the simulator, but should an email window pop-up - listing email recipient, subject and message body?

Comment: Yup, so it's not called a MFMailComposeViewController for nothing :P. When you're ready, you can just present it like any other view controller using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Sorry. Where do I place/insert  `presentViewController:animated:completion:` ? I have done some reading and understand that I can call the `presentViewController:animated:completion`: method to present the view controller, but how do I execute this? Last question - I promise :-)

Comment: `presentViewController(composer, animated: true, completion: nil)` at the very end of my code example above, or whenever you're ready to present it.

Comment: `self.presentViewController(composer, animated: true, completion: nil)`. YES! I worked it out just before you replied. Big yahoo moment for me! lol. How do I know if the partial screenshot is attached as attachment?